# Uploading a Stream of files using move_uploaded_files

Tags: php

I have been trying to upload a stream of files using the following code,

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="carousel_update.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">
for($j = 1 ; $j <= $n ; $j++)   {
        echo "<option value='$j'>$j</option>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"title[$i]\"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Image: </td><td><input type=\"file\" name=\"picture$i\"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description:</td><td><textarea name=\"description[$i]\"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Link Text: </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"link_text[$i]\"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Link URL: </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"link_url[$i]\"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Link Target: </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"link_target[$i]\"></td></tr></table></fieldset>";
        }
    }
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

In the action file carousel_update.php,

```
for($i = 1; $i<=$n ; $i++)  {
    $file = "picture".$i;
    $order = $_POST['order'][$i];
    $title = $_POST['title'][$i];
    $description = $_POST['description'][$i];
    $linktext = $_POST['link_text'][$i];
    $linkurl = $_POST['link_url'][$i];
    $linktarget = $_POST['link_target'][$i];
    $target = dirname(__FILE__). "/images/".$_FILES[$file]["name"];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
        echo "Uploaded";
    }
    else    {
        echo "Problems in uploading file";
    }
}
```

If I have to upload 3 files, I am able to upload the some images but the others show an error. I checked the server logs and it says:

```
[Tue Aug 20 12:00:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: picture2 in /var/www/akai/carousel_update.php on line 19, referer: http://127.0.0.1/akai/update_carousel.php?id=1
[Tue Aug 20 12:00:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: picture2 in /var/www/akai/carousel_update.php on line 21, referer: http://127.0.0.1/akai/update_carousel.php?id=1
[Tue Aug 20 12:00:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: picture3 in /var/www/akai/carousel_update.php on line 19, referer: http://127.0.0.1/akai/update_carousel.php?id=1
[Tue Aug 20 12:00:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: picture3 in /var/www/akai/carousel_update.php on line 21, referer: http://127.0.0.1/akai/update_carousel.php?id=1
```

I do not know what the error in mu code is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you are running into some size restrictions (HTTP_POST-Size, Maximal upload size, ...) - or you don't hava selected pictures 2 and 3 in your form?

Comment: Where is the opening PHP tag before the `for($j = 1 ; $j <= $n ; $j++)   {`?

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't have Picture 2 and 3 in your form, or they are not passed correctly to the php script.

Well, you didn't state in what circumstances you are implementing this but why don't you just use three or more input file field on the page?